# Open button on Messagebox

Tags: c#, winforms, button, messagebox, visual-studio-express

I have a WinForms application, and when it is finished running, displays a message box with just an OK button.

Is it possible to have an OPEN button on the message box too?

I found this code online:

```
public static DialogResult Show(string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons);
```

But it only gives basic commands, like `Yes / No`, `OK / Cancel`, etc. It doesn't show any open button.

I want to OPEN a text file after my program has finished running.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So do the same when .Ok is clicked

Comment: I want to give the user an option to whether they want to open it immediately.

Comment: good point, I can use the OkCancel buttons, and the OK button can be to open the text file. Good thinking there @V4Vendetta :)

Comment: @Kevdog777 Why don't you create a Windows forms and then set its size to Messagebox window ? and then add the open button.

Comment: @Searock Could do that too. My mind must've been blank when posting this question. Thanks all!

Comment: @Kevdog777 When I go blank, I switch off my monitor, relax for 2-3 minutes and then try to find out a solution and if it still does not work I ask questions here. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't have any other values in a message box rather than the default, the `MessageBoxButtons` is predefined `enum` and you can't add to it. The solution is either use some custom message box, check [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/customized-dialog), or implement your own MessageBoxForm and add your custom settings to it, check [this](http://www.techlicity.com/blog/dotnet-creating-a-custom-messagebox.html).

Answer (score 0):

The MessageBox.Show methods exposes serval overloads. You can use one of them as you like. To invoke a MessageBox, simply execute following line:

MessageBox.Show("Hi");

For information you can find on MSDN.